# Zoo Visitor - Update profile with new fields

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, safecracker-registration

EE 2.9.2 & Zoo Visitor 1.3.3

I have 20 fields, 10 of which are required for users to fill out when registering. I want the users to be able to then complete the other 10 when they have been registered. The `{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}` tag does not seem to work for these fields, I assume because they do not have any data stored in them.

So, I have to use another `{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form}`, although submitting that complains that the original 10 fields filled out during registration has not been completed. What's the best way to approach this? Use the current setup and have the required fields hidden?

Comment: This should be possible...we don't have that many fields in our setup but users can definitely fill out other fields after they have registered with the basic required fields. Can you share your code for the update tag?

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks! I have posted the code as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/paulcredmond/d5389ea5f462656f09ec

None of the fields under 'My CV' will save. These fields were not asked during the registration process but are part of the same field group.

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know what I find...looks like we worked on very similar projects! We just launched our clients job portal site (a few minor things to still address, but it's live and working!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly looking at it, I'm finding the following issue for those fields that are not saving.

You have:

```
<input type="text" name="{candidate_skype}" id="{candidate_skype}" value="{if candidate_skype}{candidate_skype}{/if}" />
```

Why is the name and id wrapped in {}?

Just use:

```
<input type="text" name="candidate_skype" id="candidate_skype" value="{if candidate_skype}{candidate_skype}{/if}" />
```

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I missed it.